# Разные маркеры на карте Yandex Maps

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Мне необходимо вывести разные кастомные маркеры на карту, подскажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать?

```
const init = () => {
        const clusterer = new CustomCluster;

        const map = new ymaps.Map(
            'map',
            {
                center: [55.76, 37.64],
                zoom: 10,
            },
            {
                // searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search',
            },
        );

        const objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
            // Включает кластеризацию
            clusterize: true,
            // Устанавливает размер ячейки кластеризации в пикселях
            gridSize: 32,
            geoObjectOpenBalloonOnClick: true,
            clusterOpenBalloonOnClick: true

        });

        objectManager.objects.options.set({
            // Указываем тип макета
            iconLayout: 'default#imageWithContent',
            // Добавляем своё изображение иконки метки
            iconImageHref: '/local/templates/assets/svg/pin.svg',
            // Указываем размеры метки
            iconImageSize: [50, 50],
            // Изменяем положение левого верхнего угла иконки относительно её точки привязки
            iconImageOffset: [-25, -25],
            // Не скрывать метку при открытии балуна
            hideIconOnBalloonOpen: false,
        });
        
        objectManager.clusters.options.set({
            clusterIconLayout: clusterer.createCluster(),
            clusterIconShape: clusterer.createIconShape(),
        });

        map.geoObjects.add(objectManager);

        $.ajax({
            url: '/local/ajax/maps-yandex.php',
            data: {
                IBLOCK_ID: params.IBLOCK_ID,
                SECTION_ID: params.PARENT_SECTION,
            },
        }).done(function(data) {
            objectManager.add(data);
        });


    };

    ymaps.ready(init);
```

При формирование json, насколько понимаю нужно указать разный options

Answer (score 0):

Для вывода кастомных маркеров с данным сценарием вы можете использовать примеры кода из Песочницы:

1. [Добавление метки с собственным изображением](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/icon_customImage).
2. [Создание кластеризатора с произвольными иконками](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/clusterer_custom_icon).
3. [Оптимальное добавление множества меток](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager).

Полезную информацию вы можете также найти в разделах Документации [Placemark](https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi-v2-1/doc/ru/v2-1/ref/reference/Placemark), [Clusterer](https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi-v2-1/doc/ru/v2-1/ref/reference/Clusterer), [ObjectManager](https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi-v2-1/doc/ru/v2-1/ref/reference/ObjectManager).

По вопросу options в JSON: описание объектов создаётся по определённой структуре, некоторые поля могут совпадать полностью (поле type, например, должно всегда иметь значение **Feature**), другие, как, например, id, должны быть уникальными. Подробнее вы можете прочитать в разделе Документации [Разработка серверной части → Структура JSON-описания объектов](https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi-v2-1/doc/ru/v2-1/dg/concepts/loading-object-manager/backend).